# mergsort printing a strange result

Tags: double, mergesort, println

I am having an issue with my merge sort, when I print out my sortedArray it only returns [ 0.0, 0.0.....] Im not sure if there is an error in my sort code or in my print line or if it has to do with doubles. The code I am us posted below.

By calling System.out.println(toString(sortedArray) I get an even more obscure answer.

Thanks for any help.

```
package mergesort;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class mergesort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = getIntArray();
        long before = System.nanoTime();
        double[] sortedArray= mergeSort(array);
        System.out.println("Sorting took  "+ (System.nanoTime() - before) +" nanoseconds ");
        System.out.println(toString(array) + "\n\n" + toString(sortedArray) + "\n main method completed in: " + (System.nanoTime() - before) + " nanoseconds.");

    }


    private static String toString(double[] array) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[ ");
        double len = array.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
            sb.append(array[i] + ", ");
        }
        sb.append(array[(int) (len - 1)] + " ]");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static double[] mergeSort(double[] array) {

        if (array.length <= 1) {
            return array;
        }
        int half = array.length / 2;
        return merge(mergeSort(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, half)),
                mergeSort(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, half, array.length)));
    }

    private static double[] merge(double[] ds, double[] ds2) {
        int len1 = ds.length, len2 = ds2.length;
        int totalLength = len1 + len2;
        double[] result = new double[totalLength];
        int counterForLeft =0,counterForRight=0,resultIndex=0;
        while(counterForLeft<len1 || counterForRight < len2){
            if(counterForLeft<len1 && counterForRight < len2){
                if(ds[counterForLeft]<= ds2[counterForRight]){
                    result[resultIndex++] =(int) ds[counterForLeft++];
                } else {
                    result[resultIndex++] =(int) ds2[counterForRight++];
                }

            }else if(counterForLeft<len1){
                result[resultIndex++] = (int) ds[counterForLeft++];

            }else if (counterForRight <len2){
                result[resultIndex++] =(int) ds2[counterForRight++];
            }
        }  
        return result;
    }

    private static double[] getIntArray() {
        double[] array = new double[10000];
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i = 0;  i < 10000; i++) {
            array[i] = (random.nextDouble() * .99999);

        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the merge method, when copying from one of the input arrays to the results, you cast to `int`. For example:

```
result[resultIndex++] =(int) ds[counterForLeft++];
```

All your doubles are in the range [0...1), so the result of casting any of them to `int` is zero. Just get rid of those casts, and you will keep your numbers in the merge result.

As an additional tip, it is much easier to debug small problems than large ones. It failed for any size greater than 2, so you should have been debugging with size 2, not 10000.

Comment: Wow, that totally slipped by me thank you so much! Just added that and it worked.

Comment: What would a test for this code look like, test as in confirming that the next double in the string is in ? If you don't mind helping im kind of lost I think using .compateTo to test is the correct way to go about this.

Comment: @Tomlangdorr If you know all your inputs will be finite numbers you can use simple double comparison.

Comment: @Tomlangdorr The easiest way to test this would be to compare your sorted array to the result of applying Arrays.sort to the original array. They should be identical.

Comment: Since Arrays.sort(array) is void how could I get it to be comparable with a double? currently I haveArrays.equals(Arrays.sort(array), sortedArray); and its not allowing it to comapare. Could I make a copy of the newly sorted array of type double then compare?

Comment: @Tomlangdorr You need to learn to read API documentation. Arrays.sort sorts in place the array it is given as its argument, so you should make a copy of your input. call Arrays.sort on it, and compare that array to your result.

Comment: Isnt Arrays.sort of type void? How can I compare my result of type double to that of type void? @PatriciaShanahan

Comment: @Tomlangdorr Compare the array you told Arrays.sort to sort, not the non-existent result of Arrays.sort.

Comment: This is what I came up with and it doesnt seem just quite right. Am I going about it the right way? At this point I feel like it might be easier to use two for loops to just read and compare the elements in my sortedArray: Arrays.sort(array);
     Arrays.toString(array);
     //System.out.println(array);
     toString(sortedArray);
     //System.out.println(sortedArray);
     if 
     (array.equals(sortedArray)){
      System.out.println("Sorted Arrays are equal");
     }
      else{
       System.out.println("Sorted Arrays are unequal?");
      }
     }

Comment: I figured out how to compare using 2 for loops. I thank you very much for your help.